# RowStatus in a table in SNMP MIB

Tags: snmp, mib

In the example MIB entry below:

```
--
-- Logging configuration
--

nsLoggingTable     OBJECT-TYPE
  SYNTAX      SEQUENCE OF NsLoggingEntry
  MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
  STATUS      current
  DESCRIPTION
    "A table of individual logging output destinations, used to control
     where various levels of output from the agent should be directed."
  ::= { nsConfigLogging 1 }

nsLoggingEntry     OBJECT-TYPE
  SYNTAX      NsLoggingEntry
  MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
  STATUS      current
  DESCRIPTION
    "A conceptual row within the logging table."
  INDEX       { nsLogLevel, IMPLIED nsLogToken }
  ::= { nsLoggingTable 1 }

NsLoggingEntry ::= SEQUENCE {
  nsLogLevel          INTEGER,
  nsLogToken          DisplayString,
  nsLogType           INTEGER,
  nsLogMaxLevel       INTEGER,
  nsLogStatus         RowStatus
}
```

Here RowStatus entry is the last one in the NsLoggingEntry, **can we put this RowStatus entry anywhere in NsLoggingEntry  (for e.g. after "nsLogToken DisplayString")**?

Comment: To answer your question, I need to understand why you're asking it.  Are you asking if you can move the "nsLogStatus   RowStatus" entry further up in the list?

Comment: yes .. that is the intention ..

Comment: I've added an answer that I believe addresses your question, but I'm still not convinced I've given you the information you were looking for.  If my response doesn't answer your core question, could you please give a little more detail why you want to move `nsLogStatus`?

Answer (score 1):

Moving the entry `nsLogStatus RowStatus` to a different location within the sequence of `NsLoggingEntry` is *possible* but you need to update the order of the columnar objects to match the order of the sequence.

To give a little more detail, `NsLoggingEntry ::= SEQUENCE` is defining the columns that will make up entries in the `nsLoggingTable`.  The MIB file should have further definition for each of those columns that will look something like,

```
nsLogStatus OBJECT-TYPE
  SYNTAX      RowStatus
  MAX-ACCESS  read-only
  STATUS      current
  DESCRIPTION "<Some great description of this column>"
  ::= { nsLoggingEntry 5 }
```

The key part of that definition is the `::= { nsLoggingEntry 5 }` line which asserts that `nsLogStatus` will be the fifth column of in rows of `nsLoggingTable`.  If you change the order of the `NsLoggingEntry` sequence, you should make sure that the individual column definitions follow that sequence.

For example, if you changed the order to be,

```
NsLoggingEntry ::= SEQUENCE {
  nsLogLevel          INTEGER,
  nsLogToken          DisplayString,
  nsLogStatus         RowStatus,
  nsLogType           INTEGER,
  nsLogMaxLevel       INTEGER
}
```

the OID assignments for each of the columns should become,

```
nsLogLevel    ::= { nsLoggingEntry 1 }
nsLogToken    ::= { nsLoggingEntry 2 }
nsLogStatus   ::= { nsLoggingEntry 3 }
nsLogType     ::= { nsLoggingEntry 4 }
nsLogMaxLevel ::= { nsLoggingEntry 5 }
```

There is one more thing to keep in mind: the index for the table should be the first column in the sequence so `nsLogLevel` should remain in it's current location, as should `nsLogToken`.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, even if the original poster did not evaluate (accept) it.